# Spring MVC 3 bind regular form to DTO

Tags: java, spring-mvc

can you bind regular HTML form (not using Springs `<form:form>)` tag to DTO? I know I get get values using @RequestParam in controller, but can I let Spring do auto bind the form to DTO? If so, how?

I cannot use Springs `<form:form>` becouse I have predefined upload form which is not compatible with springs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Remember JSP taglibs only affect the way the HTML is generated and sent to the client. So you can create exactly the same HTML manually (e.g. just use plain old HTML) and the page will function exactly the same.

Just remember to include the necessary attributes in your `<form>` and `<input>` tags, etc., and then in your controller simply bind to your form backing bean as usual.